# Arrays.asList also for maps?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have the below code:

```
Map<String, Map<Double, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<Double,String> Amap = new HashMap<>();
map.put(getValuesTypes.FUT(), HERE);
```

Instead of creating a Map first and put it at "HERE", I'm looking for a function like I could use with a `List` there `Arrays.asList(...)`
so that i can just enter at `"Here" ?.asMap({1.0,"A"}, {2.0,"B"})`

Comment: `{1.0,"A"}` is an object array, not a map

Comment: With Java 9, you will be able to use collection factory methods for creating immutable maps, see http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V- and its variants.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can initialize `HashMap` like this.

```
new HashMap<Double, String>() {
    {
        put(1.0, "ValA");
        put(2.0, "ValB");
    }
};
```

Comment: Be awere that it has hidden cost of creating extra map instance. It is called double brace initialization.

Comment: with Java 9 you can simply do `new HashMap<Double, String>(Map.of(
    1.0, "A", 
    2.0, "B"
));`

Comment: What it does is it basically creates an anonymous class from HashMap class and inside your anonymous class you use a static block. I personally would stay away from this.

Answer (score 10):

With [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
Map<Double, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(1.0, "A", 2.0, "B");
```

Answer (score 6):

Guava's [ImmutableMap.of(..)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of-K-V-) can help in this direction:

```
ImmutableMap.of(1, "a");
```

in the JDK there is only [Collections.singletonMap(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html?is-external=true#singletonMap-K-V-), but this provides you just a map with a sole pair.

There was a [discussion](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1860) in [guava project](https://github.com/google/guava) to contain a `Maps.asMap(Object... varArgs)`, bit it was stopped. So, ImmutableMap.of(...) is the way to go.

**EDIT since JDK 9**

In JDK 9 there were added new methods that do the same thing:
[Map.of(K,V)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V))

Answer (score 1):

There is no literal to initialize a map in that way. But you could use an anonymous class generating on the spot:

```
map.put(getValuesTypes.FUT(), new HashMap<Double, String>() {{
    put(1.0, "A");
    put(2.0, "B");
}});
```

though it's not recommended. I would suggest to use Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
map.put(getValuesTypes.FUT(), ImmutableMap.<Double, String>of(1.0, "A", 2.0, "B"));
```

If a number of pairs is greater than `5`, you should use their [`builder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html):

```
map.put(getValuesTypes.FUT(), 
        ImmutableMap.<Double, String>builder().put(1.0, "A")/* 5+ puts */.build());
```

Comment: Without the need to import extra libs, you can use `java.util.Collections` like so `Collections.unmodifiableMap(myHashMapInstance)`

Answer (score 0):

You can only initialize a new map by using an anonymous class. i.e.

`new HashMap<K, V>() {{
        put(key, value);
        put(key, value);
    }};`